# Import SQL bacpac from onprem to azure, error - There is already an object named in the database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, bacpac

I am trying to move my database from on-premise to Azure. Approach is to create `.bacpac` from the on-premise server, then restore it to Azure DB using `sqlpackage.exe`.

This is the command I am using:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:import 
               /tcs:"Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDB;Authentication=’Active Directory Integrated’; 
               /sf=”C:\BD-AZ\myonprembacpac.bacpac” 
               /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P1
```

While importing, I get this error:

> There is already an object named in the database.

My current on-premise database is case sensitive and having objects with same name different case. That’s why the `.bacpac` created as

```
<Property Name="Collation" Value="Latin1_General_BIN" />
```

in `mode.xml` which is expected.

My Azure and on-premise server (both) have the collation set to, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

There are other databases in that Azure DB server with a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

So for other apps, there are no issues.

- Server collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- DB collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

For my app with the issue "There is already an object named in the database":

- Server collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
- DB collation : Latin1_General_BIN

Can I import my current `.bacpac` with a `Latin1_General_BIN` collation to a server with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation without any errors?

From this article looks like it’s designed but not sure if there is a way to overcome it.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-97-which-is-the-server-collation-in-azure-sql/ba-p/744183

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not change the collation of the database first, and then use the bacpac?

Comment: @Larnu, It's hard to do it.It's a legacy project with lot of duplicate objects  , I mean same name different case. 
SELECT COUNT(name COLLATE latin1_general_ci_ai), name COLLATE latin1_general_ci_ai
FROM server.sys.all_objects
GROUP BY name COLLATE latin1_general_ci_ai
HAVING COUNT(name COLLATE latin1_general_ci_ai) > 1;

It's giving me more than 500 objects.

Comment: Of the database in Azure... That's clearly not the legacy application.

Comment: @Larnu It's a legacy one , we are moving to Azure.

Comment: So, again... *"Why not change the collation of the database first, and then use the bacpac?"* If you refuse to change the collation in azure then you need to change the database's definition and fix all the references along the way. It's one or the other.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury Azure SQL database default collection is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. We can't chance it once it created. Can you delete and re-create the SQL database with specify the DB collation : Latin1_General_BIN?

Comment: Hello @RahulChowdhury, did the error solved now?

Comment: @LeonYue - When I am importing a bacpac with Latin1_General_BIN, It's throwing me error , duplicate object present. I already tried it and failed.

Comment: @LeonYue - did you get chance to read this article, same issue I am facing , https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-97-which-is-the-server-collation-in-azure-sql/ba-p/744183